# Proof for $P(A)\cap P(B)=P(A)$ when $A \subset B$

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

This is my line of reasoning:

Since $A \subset B$, we have all elements in A are in B as well. Thus, all subsets of A are subsets of B. It follows from this that $P(A) \subset P(B)$. Since $P(A)$ is the set of subsets common to both $A$ and $B$, we have $P(A) \cap P(B) = P(A)$.

I'm not sure if "It follows from this that $P(A)⊂P(B)$" has enough validation to be included; does it need more explanation? Also, can I claim all subsets of A are subsets of B from the fact that $A \subset B$?

Comment: "all subsets of $A$ are subsets of $B$" is exactly what $P(A)\subset P(B)$ means, if you write it out.

Comment: Certainly "all subsets of $A$ are subsets of $B$" means precisely that $\mathcal P(A) \subset \mathcal P(B)$. Then, note that if $X$ and $Y$ are any two sets (not necessarily power sets) then $X \subset Y$ if and only if $X \cap Y = X$.

Answer (score 1):

In case of doubt, you can go to a more formal level:

Let $C\in P(A)$. We have $C\subset A\subset B$, hence $C\in P(B)$. It follows from this that $P(A)\subset P(B)$.